# Production website becomes unresponsive on certain pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-manager

I have a weird issue that just started popping up for our customers. The portal they've been using for years has started freezing on some of the pages that the user navigates to. I tried restarting the IIS Server, the site within and the Application Pool under which the site is site is running. No difference.

In Chrome Dev Tools I can see that it is always one of these three calls that take time to complete:

[image]

When it happens, one of those three calls will report that the request is not finished, like this:

[image]

When eventually the call completes, I can see that the Content Download took 3.8 minutes. Not sure whether it is relevant or not, but it is always 3.8 minutes:

[image]

Did anyone else encounter a similar situation? Is there a suggestion on how to figure out what is happening all of a sudden that triggers these type of behaviours?

TIA,
Ed

Edit: The resource that fails to load after 3.8 minutes always generates a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error:

[image]

Edit2: Thanks to all of you trying to help. A little update: I was able to isolate to problem to an issue with the server not serving some of the files. either *.css or *.js. The setting is that of two identical servers placed behind a load balancer. Apparently, the load balancer software was recently updated and right after that we started having these issues. I am working closely with the IT department of our client, trying to figure out what is the impact of the newer version that seems to have triggered all this drama.

Comment: Browser side timing is just one side of equation. You have to dig into at least IIS log files to see what are the values of time-taken for those requests to confirm if the slowness indeed comes from IIS (as something in between can also slow things down). The deeper you dig into the issue, the closer you are to the culprit.

Comment: Does it happen when you are using page with data tables?

Comment: try to capture the failed request tracing and check how much time the page takes to load and which module is taking longer time to resonde.

Comment: @Adlorem - yes, all the pages that freeze when I try to navigate there contain data tables. In the Network page of DevTools I can see that the ".../Content/datatables?..." and ".../bundles/datatables?..." is requested on each page I try to navigate to. Can you think of a reason why that would be a problem?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal - thanks for your suggestion. As I mentioned, it is always one of the three resources in my screenshot that take 3.8 minutes to load: datatables, css or jquery. The delay reported is always 3.8 minutes, which is really weird.

Comment: The problem is probably not connected directly with your application server, but how application handles data. I assume that you are trying to fetch data from sql to preset it in page tables. You should check if there is a problem with sql tables containing large amount of data, especially if there is a procedure/method that fetches data for pagination and joins tables. Poorly written sql requests can lead to tremendous lags you described.

Comment: I have added an update as "Edit2" in the ticket above, providing an update on my issue. Thanks to all of you trying to help. It is really appreciated.